# I'm having an issue with a hover effect

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm having an issue with a hover effect implemented on my squarespace website. The effect works fine on desktop. On mobile, the images all appear normally and when I click on them they take me to the correct link. But when I press back on the browser, the image disappears. Could someone advise?

```
<a href="https://workitoutgym.com/womeninfo">
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5547fb28e4b035cc76d1df27/t/5e24c3a05c97ae22c794c67a/1579467680832/women.jpg"
onmouseover="this.src='https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5547fb28e4b035cc76d1df27/t/5e24c3da6764070705e3c1c9/1579467738774/women+hover.jpg'"
onmouseout="this.src='https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5547fb28e4b035cc76d1df27/t/5e24c3a05c97ae22c794c67a/1579467680832/women.jpg'"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your hover image is actually just a 70% tinted version of the original, it's easier to just adjust the opacity on hover. This should resolve your bug as well:

```css
.example-link img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 250ms;
}

.example-link:hover img {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<a class="example-link" href="https://workitoutgym.com/womeninfo">
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5547fb28e4b035cc76d1df27/t/5e24c3a05c97ae22c794c67a/1579467680832/women.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: Its not in my Custom CSS settings, It actually an embedded code in the code block on squarespace, using html coding so this seems to not  be working.

Comment: @AlissaLaurie You'll need to understand some HTML and CSS basics to make changes to that. The CSS selector used would depend on the way the template is built, and you may not have sufficient control to add a class to the link.